# DRF - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two Json Data, and I have created separate endpoint for saving below json data in to database and I have shared related model and serializer and i am able to save data perfectly without any issues with this, and please scroll down for issue detail

Album json:

```
  {
    "id": "dsadad-dsds-gfgf",
    "title": "Album name",
    "description": "Albumdescription",
    "url": "https://example.com/albums/dsadad-dsds-gfgf"
 }
```

Albums model:

```
class Albums(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Albums Serializer :

```
class AlbumsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tracks= serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='people-detail'
    )
    url = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Albums
        fields = ('id', 'title','tracks','url')
```

I have second json data as below which needs to be saved in database by identifying relation between albums attribute in below json to the above saved model data, so below is the code

```
{
    "id": "dsdsd-fdfd0-jkjh",
    "name": "erika",
    "albums": [
      "https://example.com/albums/dsadad-dsds-gfgf"
    ],
    "url": "https://example.com/track/dsdsd-fdfd0-jkjh"
  }
```

Model:

```
class Tracks(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    albums= models.ForeignKey(Albums,related_name='tracks',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    albums= serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Tracks
        fields = ('id', 'name','albums')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        albums_data = validated_data.pop('albums')
        for album_url in albums_data:
            movie = models.Albums.objects.get(url=album_url)
            models.Tracks.objects.create(albums=movie, **validated_data)
        return models.Tracks
```

views are just modelviewset for each individual serializers

I am getting error as and also please advice, is there anything wrong in approach, sensing something wrong in Create method, when urls are present in json data to identify parent and child relation, is this right approach ?

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback of the exception, please?

Comment: this line is wrong `return models.People`. You need to return the created instance and not the model class. I am not sure where you are using this serializer but since you are creating multiple people objects, you can return the last instance. Also, it's probably better to import the individual model classes into your namespace instead of the entire `models` file

Comment: Thank you both of you for responding to my query, I am using serializer in viewset , and I have taken the last instance of the people object, issue got resolved .  Thank you Ken issue is resolved